# Allow number, letters and any symbol in my string

Tags: jquery, regex, string, alphanumeric

I have this script that return true if in my string are only letters and spaces.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z\s]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Solo lettere ammesse");
```

How can add numbers and "," "-" like allow values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update:

`A-z` also covers characters with [ASCII value](http://www.asciitable.com/) 91 to 96 which is undesirable as per the requirement mentioned in the question. Use `A-Za-z` instead. Thus, the correct regex would be:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9-,\s]*$
```

### Original answer:

Use `^[A-z0-9-,\s]*$`

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[A-z0-9-,\s]*$/i.test(value);
}, "Solo lettere ammesse");
```

---

Good website for regex making and testing http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: it Works, thanks so much! If I want add any symbol I can add after "," ?